# Advanced Custom Fields: how do I check to see if a value is set in an field?

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

How do I check and see if a value is set in an Advanced Custom Field?

Comment: Your research efforts are …?

Comment: @toscho - looking through the plugin documentation: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/getting-started/

Comment: You didn't look through it all, then.  Menu item 4 -> functions -> click "get_field" -> Usage -> if/else example.

Comment: Matt, Research Efforts = code references you found while looking the documentation + better description of the problem (Do you mean front or back-end?) :.....: Also, the Content of your Question is exactly the same as the Title: it really makes it look like WPSE is a magic box where you drop a one line issue and some solution will self-generate...

Comment: Can't understand the downvotes. I have the very same problem: Some dev created some field, which is not shown in the backend of any page or post, but apparently used to render HTML in a PHP source. I just want to quickly inspect what the current value is. I can neither access PHP files nor the database directly. "How do I check and see if a value is set in an Advanced Custom Field?" is exactly my question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can see in the [docs](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/code-examples/) that you get the values by `get_field()`, so do something like this:

```
$values = get_field( 'field_name' );
if ( $values ) {
    echo 'A value is set';
} else {
    echo 'A value is not set';
}
```

Change `field_name` to your wanted field.

Comment: That obviously does not help if you are not allowed to add or edit any PHP on the site.